# Использована память на только что созданном разделе nvme ssd

Tags: linux, ssd

Создал 2 подряд раздела ext4 на 2гб и на 1гб, в обоих уже было занято пространство в 2гб 100Мб и 50мб на 1гб.
Смонтировал эти разделы, записал немного мусора и удалил, теперь занято 6мб на 2гб и 2.5мб на 1гб.
Кто-нибудь объяснит что это? 
(ssd - Samsung 970 evo plus 250gb m.2) (всё было сделано на Линухе)

Comment: ассоциация: [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)

Comment: @user7860670, здесь похоже на резерв под журнал или что-то такое, что корректируется в процессе работы, а по умолчанию создаётся как 5%, потому что резерв для суперпользователя, насколько я помню, сам по себе не уменьшается.